# Раскодирование строки с помощью decodeURI

Tags: javascript

```
var utm = 'utm_term'
var number = (window.location.toString().substr(window.location.toString().indexOf(utm + '=') + utm.length + 1, 50)).toLowerCase();
```

С помощью UTM-метки вытаскиваю значение. Если она закодирована, например, таким образом:

```
%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD+6s
```

То не могу раскодировать её методом `decodeURI(str)`.

Могу раскодировать таким образом:

```
decodeURI('%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD+6s')
```

То есть напрямую, но если попробовать `decodeURI(number)`, то ничего не получается.

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать? Что должно находится в number?

Comment: http://test.com/utm_term=ключевое+слово
number = ключевое слово
но в основном значение метки такое:
http://test.com/utm_term=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD+6s
number, соответственно равен этому же. мне нужно его раскодировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `number` получается `"d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c+%d0%b0%d0%b9%d"`, что несколько не очень равно `"%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD+6s"`.

Если хотите распарсить запрос в URL, то, собственно, распарсите по-честному:

```
var query = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {query[item.split("=")[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item.split("=")[1])})
```

А потом уже обращайтесь к параметру `query.utm_term`, там будут ваша строка `"купить+айфон+6s"`.

Comment: Так. Не получается.
Во-первых, мне нужно обращаться к number, а не к utm_term, а, во-вторых, если и обращаться с number, то переменная возвращает undefined. Помогите разобраться :(

Comment: @Lamer_2005 Дайте полный URL.

Comment: http://up-context.ru/?utm_term=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD+6s

Comment: @Lamer_2005 И какой номер вам надо получить?

Comment: номер? мне нужна utm метка (купить+айфон+6s)

Comment: @Lamer_2005 Я захожу на вашу страницу, выолняю код в отладочной консоли, смотрю значение `query.utm_term`, получаю ваш айфон. Что конкретно у вас не работает?

Comment: Оп. Действительно, работает. Я обращался к utm, а не к utm_term. Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: @Lamer_2005 Галочку на ответе поставить не забудьте. :)

Comment: Стараюсь, только зарегистрировал аккаунт. Нет репутации для того, чтобы вам галочку поставить. Сейчас попробую решить эту проблему)

Comment: @Lamer_2005 Галочку можно поставить всегда. Это для нажатия на стрелку вверх нужно 15 репы.

Comment: Все, понял, поставил ;)